# Reading URL in PHP/HTACCESS

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to create a system that reads a URL provided by the user and then slices it to an array, so it can output different pages from the outcome.

Let me create a sample pseudocode for this

```
//Url in borwser is http://example.com/user/frank
//this is index.php file in examplepage.com
//folders user and user/frank do not exist

$url = read_url();
//$url[0] = 'example.com';
//$url[1] = 'user';
//$url[2] = 'frank';

if($url[1]=='user' && $url[2]=='frank'){
    include_frank_page():
}else if($url[1]=='user' && $url[2]=='john'){
    include_john_page():
}else{
    include_user_error_page():
}
```

How can I do such a thing? I know WordPress does something like this, but I can't find a part of the code that does that. Does this have something to do with `.htacces` file it creates?

If you will provide me any link to any description or tutorial, I will be very thankful.

**EDIT:**
Ok, `FallbackResource /index.php` is exactly what I need, but there is a 502 Proxy Error.

I have `.htacces` that looks like this:

```
FallbackResource /test/index.php
```

And `index.php` in `test`

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Both of those are in 'test' folder in my `example.com` root directory. I want to do this only in this folder for obvious reasons.

When I type `example.com/test/aaa` result is '/test/aaa' - ok.

When I type `example.com/test/aaa/bbb` result is '/test/aaa/bbb' - ok.

When I type `example.com/test/` there is "502 proxy error". How can I avoid that?

**EDIT 2:** 
Also, when I created folder `test2` inside my `test` folder, and typed `example.com/test/test2` - there was also 502 proxy error.

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on specifically? You seem to have a workable idea?

Comment: Actually, I have done nothing yet. I dont know where to start, how to enable that functions. I dont even know how to google this! Thats why I came here

Comment: Just to clarify, you repeatedly refer to `.htacces` - it should be `.htaccess` (2 `s`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a "front controller" in `.htaccess` that routes all requests to a single file, eg. `index.php`. (This is what WordPress does).

Then, in `index.php` you examine the URL and load the appropriate content.

For example, in `.htaccess`:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

This routes all requests for non-existent files through `index.php` in the document root. (WordPress uses a mod_rewrite implementation.)

Then, in `index.php` you can do something like:

```
// Actual HTML pages stored in a (hidden) subdirectory called "/pages"
$pageDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pages';
$pages = array (
    '/home' => 'home.php',
    '/about' => 'about.php',
    '/contact => 'contact.php',
);

// $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] contains the URL of the request
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (isset($pages[$url])) {
    include($pageDir.'/'.$pages[$url]);
} else {
    // NB: The "error-404.php" page will need to return the appropriate HTTP status
    include($pageDir.'/error-404.php');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted.
Although I have 502 Proxy Error - I added details on my main post. If you could anwser I could be grateful.

Comment: If you are getting a "502 Proxy Error" on those specific requests then you probably have a conflict with other directives. You're using a `/test` subdirectory. Do you have a `.htaccess` file in the parent/root directory? Or directives in the server config/VirtualHost? `.htaccess` files are inherited along the filesystem path. As a quick test, you could include `RewriteEngine On` at the top of your `/test/.htaccess` file. This prevents any mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` being processed (by default).

Comment: No, I dont have .htacces in parent directory, and when I used 'RewriteEngine On' it didnt helped.

Comment: OK. I have just copied the code from wordpress .htacces, added /test to the beggining and now it all works great.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. However, the `FallbackResource` should have worked OK, so that's a puzzle. What version of Apache are you using?